# Limit taxonomy to one subforum

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes

I've run into an issue when designing my forum in Drupal 7.
I'm using the Forum core module and multiple taxonomy lists. Each of those taxonomy lists has its use in different subforums. However, my current configuration shows all of the drop down lists in all of my subforums.

So my question is how can I prevent that some taxonomy lists are showing on certain subforums? Would this need another module or should I make a new content type for each subforum?